# Автоматизация Python

Tags: python, автоматизация

Задача в том чтобы скрипт заходить в папку писал данные в файл выходил из папки и заходил в другую папку прописывая уже другие данные Допустим есть папки папка1 папка2 и папка3 в них лежат файлы с настройками в которые нужно внести новые данные из другого файла например файл test Нужно чтобы скрипт копировал данные из файла test 1 строку вставлял в текстовый файл в папке папка1 сохранял файл Далее заходил в папку папка 2 копировал данные из файла test 2 строку и вставлял в файл в папке 2 и так далее У кого есть идеи как это можно реализовать или в какую сторону копать

```py
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  old_data = f.read()

new_data = old_data.replace('Test', 'Test12345')

with open ('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(new_data)
```

Этот код работает но мне нужно чтобы вместо Test12345 Вставлялись данные из файла со списком нужных данных (новые данные будут на новой строке) И еще нужно чтобы папки менялись Например в папке1 данные из первой строчки в папке2 данные из 2 строчки и так далее

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Он меняет нужные данные на те которые мне нужно но нужно сделать так чтобы менял на данные из списка и менял папки как это реализовать я еще не понял

Comment: Добавьте код с пояснением в сам вопрос, чтобы было от чего плясать вообще

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите автоматически перезаписать несколько файлов строками из конкретного файла.

Данный код перезаписывает первый файл на первую строку из `settings.txt`, второй файл на вторую и т.д.:

```
settings_link = "C:\\Temp\\settings.txt"
file_links = ["C:\\Temp\\1\\f1.txt", \
              "C:\\Temp\\2\\f2.txt", \
              "C:\\Temp\\1\\f3.txt", ]

with open(settings_link, 'r') as settings:
    for line, link in zip(settings, file_links):
        with open(link, 'w') as file:
            file.write(line)
```

Или если записать все пути в отдельный файл:

```
settings_link = "C:\\Temp\\settings.txt"
links_link = "C:\\Temp\\links.txt"

file_links = []
with open(links_link, 'r') as links:
    for link in links:
        file_links.append(link.rstrip())

with open(settings_link, 'r') as settings:
    for line, link in zip(settings, file_links):
        with open(link, 'w') as file:
            file.write(line)
```

Comment: Спасибо код работает Но он полностью переписывает файл А мне нужно чтобы он заменил одно слово на то что берет из файла Например в файле который нужно переписать слово 'wallet' заменилось на 1 строчку из файла со списком Если конечно такое можно реализовать У меня в примере он так и менял слово Test на Test12345

Comment: @Кактус вы же сами написали в теле вопроса функцию замены слова, так что просто измените код таким образом, чтобы перебирать нужные вам файлы и заменять слова на нужные вам строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, примерно так (код набросал, но не проверял):

```
import os

with open ('replace.txt', 'r') as r:
    for i,line in enumerate(r, 1):
        data_file = os.path.join('A'+str(i), 'test.txt')
        with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
            old_data = f.read()
        new_data = old_data.replace('Test', line.strip())
        with open(data_file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Спасибо код работает и меняет именно строку с названием которое прописано в коде А как изменить название папки по которым он бегает было не 1 а например начиналось с буквы например A A1 A2 и так далее

Comment: @Кактус Ну соответственно будет что-то типа `data_file = os.path.join('A'+str(i), 'test.txt')`

Comment: Спасибо все работает только вот когда строка заменяется ставятся пробелы например мне нужно заменить данные в кавычках "Данные" на "Данные12345678901234" то получается как то так "Данные12345678901234    " Если вписывать данные такой же длины то проблем нет а если переписывать короткие на более длинные появляются пробелы

Comment: @Кактус Попробуйте `line.strip()`, добавил в код

Comment: Да все работает Большое спасибо